# Python stacked histogram grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization

How can I create a stacked Histogram like this:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as P
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

%pylab inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 4)
mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*P.randn(1000,2)
n, bins, patches = P.hist(x, 10, normed=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
P.show()
```

For grouped data.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'group': [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]})
```

As
`df1.A.hist(by=df1.group, bins='doane', stacked=True)` or

```
df1.A.hist(by=df1.group, bins='doane')
```

only result in:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your DataFrame so that each group is in a different column and then generate the histogram.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'group': [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]})
df1.pivot(columns='group', values='A').plot.hist(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Edit: Added the `stacked=True` parameter to `hist()`